# risking missing

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

1. As a secretary, I always risked forgetting to take notes while the discussion was most interesting, as I was concentrated on listening.
2. As a secretary, I always risked missing taking notes while the discussion was most interesting, as I was concentrated on listening.

I am reasonably certain that the first sentence is correct, and that's what I am using now. But I started from the second one, and while I found it ugly to have two consecutive gerunds, I would say that it is grammatically correct as well. Am I wrong?  What would a native speaker write?

Comment: ***missing*** doesn't work at all here, but ***failing** [ + **infinitive** verb]* might be better than ***forgetting***

Comment: I don't think it's syntactically possible for two consecutive ***-ing*** forms to both be "gerunds", but I stand to be corrected on that. Nevertheless, there's nothing unusual about constructions like *I'm **missing seeing** my family.*

Comment: You wouldn't miss taking notes, but you might miss taking a note of something important.

Comment: risked forgetting something sounds OK to me but risked missing taking notes is not great.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Challenge accepted! "The secretary thought about *commencing taking notes*, but then got distracted." I *believe* that has 2 gerunds in a row (the second is the direct object of the first), but I may be mistaken. That sentence was fun to come up with, but I agree it also doesn't sound great.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck: Well, that inspired me to come up with [*We talked about **going climbing,***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22talked+about+going+climbing%22), and I don't think anyone could say *that's* not very natural. So thanks for forcing the issue - I stood to be corrected, and you brought that about!

Answer (score 0):

> risk
>
> to take a chance on
>
> Jack **risks making** everyone angry with his stupid statements.

The verb risk is followed by a gerund.

[list of verbs followed by gerund or infinitive](https://www.thoughtco.com/list-of-verbs-followed-by-gerund-or-infinitives-1211246)

rather than **risked missing taking notes**, I would use:

**risked not taking notes**
OR
**risked forgetting to take notes**

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatically correct, with one small correction: “... as I was **concentrating** on listening.” As for my preference between the two sentences, I would choose the second sentence, but it is better to use “I often missed taking notes” instead.

Comment: But in fact I did not often miss taking notes. However I often risked missing, then I realised the risk and in fact took the note.